# Polar plot with small values and coordinate transformations leads to a "Dimension too large error"

Tags: pgfplots, polar

**EDIT : As it seems to be a bug in `pgfplots` an issue has been opened:  https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/360**

While plotting polar axes, I faced an issue when transforming small quandtities with the `y coord trafo/y coord inv trafo` options.

My plots are basically sine functions show in the polar domain. As an example take the following cosine `cos(3\x)`. This function has positive and negative values and is plotted as expected in an `axis` environment.

[image]

Now if one wants to plot this very same function inside a `polaraxis` environment, here is what comes out :

[image]

Basically, negative values are handled as a 180° phase shift, instead of being simply shown as a negative value at the defined angular coordinate.

This behavior can be circumvented with some well-chosen `y coord trafo/y coord inv trafo`. In this very case,

```
y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+2},
y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-2},
```

works just fine.

[image]

However, if some small values have to be handled, say around `1e-6` amplitude instead of 1 as in the above examples, the computation fails due to precision errors.
These problems should be solvable through the `fpu` unit, but I can't figure the correct sequence.
I tried e.g

```
y coord trafo/.code={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}\pgfmathparse{#1+2e-6}\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}},
y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}\pgfmathparse{#1-2e-6}\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}},
```

but this leads to illegal unit of measure errors.

Here is the MWE to reproduce the figures and the problem once the commented part is reactivated.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{cos(3*\x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{cos(3*\x)});
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+2},
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-2},
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{cos(3*\x)});
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Not working
% \begin{tikzpicture}
%     \begin{polaraxis}[%
%             xmin=0,
%             xmax=360,
%             ymin=-2e-6,
%             ymax=2e-6,
%             y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1+2e-6}},
%             y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1-2e-6}},
%             domain = 0:360,
%         ]
%         \addplot+ ({\x},{1e-6*cos(3*\x)});
%     \end{polaraxis}
% \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using `fpu` for the coordinate transformations is good. You just need to add `/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{cos(3*\x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{cos(3*\x)});
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2,
            ymax=2,
            y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+2},
            y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-2},
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{cos(3*\x)});
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Now working
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{polaraxis}[%
            xmin=0,
            xmax=360,
            ymin=-2e-6,
            ymax=2e-6,
            y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparseFPU{#1+2e-6}},
            y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparseFPU{#1-2e-6}},
            domain = 0:360,
        ]
        \addplot+ ({\x},{1e-6*cos(3*\x)});
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the proposal ! I was totally missing the `\pgfmathsmuggle` and others. However, The ticklabels should read as `-2,-1,0,1,2` which is not the case with your proposal unfortunately

Comment: @BambOo Maybe I am saying something stupid, but aren't you shifting the ticks? That is, you have `ymin=-2e-6,ymax=2e-6,` and then with `y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparseFPU{#1+2e-6}},` you add `2e-6`, so y should vary between 0 and `4e-6`. What am I missing?

Comment: No, it's not stupid, but this is why there is the `y coord inv trafo`. Basically I shift the plot to avoid actual negative amplitude-related problems, but I correct the ticks using the `inv trafo`

Comment: @BambOo You are right. There seems to be some problem with the scaled y ticks. If you add `scaled y ticks=false,` then the ticks will be correct (but look ugly).

Comment: So it seems indeed ...

Comment: @BambOo, since you and the cat agree that this is very likely a bug, would you file an issue in the tracker again!? Thanks in advance again.

Comment: @StefanPinnow issue posted !